# Make annoying executable invisible to bash tab completion (cd-it8 etc)

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, auto-completion

When using the command line, `cd` is one of the most frequently used shell commands. I've gotten used to the ability to type `cd`, pressing `tab`, and then pressing `tab` again to see what directories there are to `cd` into. Ubuntu has recently started including the `colord` package and its tools start with `cd`. Now if I press `cd` and `tab`, I get this:

```
$ cd
cd                 cd-fix-profile     cd-it8             
cd-create-profile  cd-iccdump
```

How can I make sure all those `cd-*` executables don't show up when I'm using the command line? I assume they are necessary for the OS, so I can't just move them out or rename them; however, I don't want them to be completed or even visible when I'm in bash.

Note that this is under bash 4.4.20(1) which is what comes with Ubuntu 18.04.

As an aside: are those executables still included in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Can you get into the habit of hitting space after `cd` before hitting tab? BTW you will likely experience equivalent behavior with other commands ex. `ls` which will complete to `lsattr`,`lshw` etc. unless you add whitespace before hitting tab

Comment: thanks, the idea behind this question is not to get into the habit :)

Comment: apparently starting with bash 5, you can do the following:

`complete -W '$(compgen -c|grep -v ^cd-)' -I`

(that's a capital i)

Comment: Hitting tab expands the current word, that is the correct behavior .... so it is the right habit to press space after `cd` and you are better off adapting that. Because if you deviate too much from the standards in your bash/terminal, you cannot work somewhere else anymore, e.g. on a server.

Comment: @pLumo thanks, but I'd like to customize bash for my own liking, I don't care what you put on your own server, I can manage this issue on my own when I get to it. This is a matter of personal preference and I'm not going to argue for or against it, feel free to accept it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html),

> **EXECIGNORE**
> A colon-separated list of shell patterns (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)) defining the list of filenames to be ignored by command search using PATH.  Files whose full  pathnames  match  one of these patterns are not considered executable files for the purposes of completion and command execution via PATH lookup.

So add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
EXECIGNORE="*/cd-*:"
```

---

I do not have those `cd-*` commands, but here is another example:

```
$ EXECIGNORE=
$ ex<TAB>
ex                          exit                        exo-open                    expiry
exec                        exo-csource                 exo-preferred-applications  export
exifautotran                exo-desktop-item-edit       expand                      expr
$ xfc<TAB>
xfce4-terminal          xfce4-terminal.wrapper  xfconf-query
$ EXECIGNORE="*/ex?*:*/xfconf-query:"
$ ex<TAB>
ex      exec    exit    export
$ xfc<TAB>
$ xfce4-terminal
```

It illustrates an important point: Shell builtins are not excluded (`exec`, `exit` and `export` are still suggested in the completion), since they are not searched using PATH.

Comment: thanks, that worked. However it didn't work when I first tried it out by writing `EXECIGNORE="*/cd-*:" bash` and trying inside that. Even though `echo $EXECIGNORE` showed the right thing, it still would list `cd-it8` and the rest in tab completion. So that's a gotcha. Doing things the way you suggested, though, worked perfectly.

Comment: Use `export EXECIGNORE="*/cd-*:"` instead.